# How i can remove shadow from glossy metallic?

Tags: shadows

On my wooden box i have glossy and metallic materials and i want to get rid of this blue tire shadow on the wooden box without loosing the glossy and metallic materials.
When i cut off glossy or Metallic then there is no shadow.[image]

Comment: I don’t think that’s a shadow - looks like a reflection to me. Try increasing your glossy roughness and/or reduce the amount of glossy with your mix node - that might help. Otherwise, please post an image of your material nodes from the Node Editor window.

Comment: For my blue tire object I unchecked glossy from cycles setting and it worked perfectly. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Great - glad to help. It would be good if you could post an answer describing your solution and accept it so that others can benefit if they have a similar problem.

Comment: @Aamir your image shows a "mix shader" which only has one shader (another "mix shader"), so nobody can really understand your material setting, and learn how you corrected this issue. Also, eg, that seems wood, so what you mean by "metallic"? An answer would be perfect to show what you changed and the effect.